# Reading specific elements from a CSV file in C++

Tags: c++, csv, file-read

I'm trying to create a reference program which I think will use an excel spreadsheet to hold information for reading only. I want the user to be able to select a topic from an option list and have the information in the appropriate cell be fed back to them. The program is being written in C++. My question is, how do I access specific cells from a spreadsheet from my program? I've researched it a little and I've seen that I want to save my file as a csv and use fscanf to read the contents, but I'm at a loss as to how I would do this part. I googled it and found this thread:

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/204808/parsing-a-csv-file-separated-by-semicolons

but I think it reads in all of the data from the CSV? From what I can tell anyways. And I only want to pull specific elements. Is that possible?

Comment: You will have to read the whole file to be able to access the desired elements (and ignore the rest)

Answer (score 1):

If you only want specific elements, you would still have to parse all contents of the file until you reach those elements. You don't have to store values you don't need, but you do need to parse them to advance in the file.

Comment: So create an array and feed the elements of the file into the array to search through?

Answer (score 0):

Are you invoking the program from Excel? If you are, a little VBA goes a long way. You could always only export the cells of interest ready for your C++ program to read in.

Otherwise, other answers are correct. However, you don't need to load the entire file into memory at once. You can use std::fstream to open the file and read in each line of the file, parsing in the required information for each line.

Comment: No, the program should ask for a topic from the user and then access the excel program, and this reference database idea I have is for a possible topic for a final program I might be doing in my C++ class, so I have to write the program completely in C++.

The second part of what you said looks like my best option, I'll look into that. Thanks for the advice :)

Comment: @Monique no problem. As a heads up, try Boost Tokenizer to split a string into a collection of strings delimited by the commas; [Boost Tokenizer](http://tinyurl.com/ct3dmy6)